# to have been vs. to be following past tense

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is correct:

> I was fortunate to have been selected for an award.

Or

> I was fortunate to be selected for an award.

To be clear, both events happened in the past, that is, *I was fortunate 2 years ago when I was selected for the award*...

Answer (score 1):

Their meaning is essentially the same but I would use them in slightly different circumstances - which perhaps only an experienced native speaker might appreciate.

Essentially, if it was the first time the listener was hearing about the award, I think I would choose the former. Equally if the point was incidental to more important information I think I would also use the *to have been* form.

In other circumstances, where I was repeating something already known, and/or it was the essential point about what I was saying - perhaps I might use *to be selected*.

But this is a finely nuanced issue and only something that people with an intimate realtionship with everyday English might grasp.

Answer (score -1):

Both 'to have been selected' and 'to be selected' are in passive forms of Perfect Infinitive, and 'Indefinite infinitive (for progressive infinitive also the passive is same.)

To select/ to be selecting A.V.- to be selected P.V.

to have selected/ to have been selecting AV - to have been selected P.V.

Infinitive are non-finite with no tenses being attached. However, it follows the pattern "He eats.../ He is eating.../ He has eaten.../ He has been eating, which in PV will be (take any object), is eaten/ is being eaten/ has been eaten/ has been eaten (The last two are similar)

Meaning-wise, they sound similar, and they are.